# Rows not ordered properly with group by

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT userid,SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(data, '\"!', -1), '!\"', 1)+0 AS num 
FROM table
WHERE type=2
ORDER BY num DESC LIMIT 5
```

This picks up the number between !x! in a string and tries to return the number and order the rows by that number. It works fine.

**However, I don't know how to return unique user ids.**

Adding ORDER BY userid returns the rows without ordering by num:

```
SELECT userid,SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(data, '\"!', -1), '!\"', 1)+0 AS num 
FROM table
WHERE type=2
GROUP BY userid
ORDER BY num DESC LIMIT 5
```

Distinct doesn't work either:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(userid),SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(data, '\"!', -1), '!\"', 1)+0 AS num 
FROM table
WHERE type=2
ORDER BY num DESC LIMIT 5
```

I am out of ideas..

Example:

```
id    userid     data
1       56       !100!
2       22       !90!
3       56       !200!
```

Result should be:

```
userid      num
56          200
22          90
```

Comment: Are there multiple possible results for each userid? If so, `DISTINCT` won't give you what you need. What is your criterion for choosing which of the multiple records should be returned for each userid?

Comment: There are multiple rows with the same userid, but no userid should be return twice. Unique userids with the highest num should be returned.

Comment: @Michael added example to my main post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT userid,MAX(num) num FROM
(SELECT userid,SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(data, '\"!', -1), '!\"', 1)+0 AS num  
FROM table 
WHERE type=2) A
GROUP BY userid;
```